# Connecting Excel 2010 VBA to Oracle using 11g client

Tags: oracle, excel, vba, adodb

I have an Excel macro that I have used to connect to Oracle 10g just fine.
I've brought that sheet over to a PC with the Oracle 11g 64-bit client installed, and Excel 2010, and now it doesn't work.  I get an error along the lines of
"Microsoft ODBC For Oracle
The Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found"

Help?

Comment: Excel is 32 bit, right?  The client needs to be the same level as the application.  Did you create an ODBC Data Source?

Did you try connecting to the database using SQLPLus?  Get that working first.  Then you can debug ODBC if you still have a problem.

Comment: Angelo, I was just about to add that I'm on the 32-bit excel, and decided that I probably need the 32-bit client. Downloading now and will let you know.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the 32-bit client worked.
:)